# Trigger an Azure Pipeline with new Pull Request then conditions

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have an Azure pipeline that is part of a bigger project. This pipeline is a CI pipeline for a tool. We have the following triggers set to the pipeline:

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - feature/*
      - main
      - hotfix/*
  paths:
    include:
      - mainTool/*
    exclude:
      - mainTool/extensions/*
```

According to this snippet, my pipeline runs only for branches with these names, if any changes in the mainTool directory but not in the extensions subdirectory is changed.

This works fine for my purposes, but I want to make the pipeline ALSO run once when a new PR is created, this way it would build and push the correct version of the tool for this branch. is there a way to achieve that or should I just settle to rebuilding the image for every push (to branches with active PRs)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61350543/how-do-i-trigger-build-and-test-on-a-pull-request-in-azure-devops

Comment: @Adji_PA I want to run the pipeline once regardless of the triggering conditions, then I have the set of conditions that I want to be checked for each push while a Pull Request is active. one or the other on their own is easy, but both together is tricky and that's my question

Comment: I see that it's a possible duplicate, because it sounds like what you want is basically what the Build Validation does. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61358231/6681261. 

So...the snippet will trigger, when there are pushed branches above, and when files under mainTool/* are changed

But what you're saying is...say you have main branch, and feature/new_feat branch. As you make a PR from feature/new_feat into main branch, feature_x branch also goes through build_validation (again), and takes the YAML above, and it builds your tool. Is that right? Can you make the use case clearer?